# Get default SQL Server Instance On Local Machine Using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, instance

There is way to check which instance is Main/Default.

I use this

```
 private void GetDataSources2()  
 {  
     string ServerName = Environment.MachineName;  

     RegistryView registryView = Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem ? RegistryView.Registry64 : RegistryView.Registry32;  

     using (RegistryKey hklm = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, registryView))  
     {  
         RegistryKey instanceKey = hklm.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL", false);  

         if (instanceKey != null)  
         {  
             foreach (var instanceName in instanceKey.GetValueNames())  
             {  
                 Console.WriteLine(ServerName + "\\" + instanceName);  
             }  
         }  
     }  
 }
```

To find all instance. After it I check whether the database exists on any instance. If not I want to create it on main instance.

Comment: What is "Main" SQL instance? Is it the name of the instance? Or do you mean default instance by using word "Main"?

Comment: Ye I added main mean default

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms143744(v=sql.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) default intance name is `MSSQLSERVER`:

> The default instance name is MSSQLSERVER; it does not require a client to specify the name of the instance to make a connection.

Therefore to define if an instance is default it is necessary to check if the name of the instance is `MSSQLSERVER`.

Here are changes that can be made to your code to define if an instance is default:

```
private void GetDataSources2()
{
    string ServerName = Environment.MachineName;

    RegistryView registryView = Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem ? RegistryView.Registry64 : RegistryView.Registry32;

    using (RegistryKey hklm = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, registryView))
    {
        RegistryKey instanceKey = hklm.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL", false);

        if (instanceKey != null)
        {
            foreach (var instanceName in instanceKey.GetValueNames())
            {
                if (instanceName == "MSSQLSERVER")
                    // To reference default instance we should use name "ServerName".
                    Console.WriteLine(ServerName);
                else
                    // To reference non default instances we should use name "ServerName\InstanceName".
                    Console.WriteLine(ServerName + "\\" + instanceName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But  someone  can change this name. Alternatively, you can connect to the default via localhost itself and check. But I don't know if this is a good solution.

Comment: According to documentation `MSSQLSERVER` is reserved keyword. If the name of the instance is `MSSQLSERVER` then this instance is default and to connect to it you can use name "ServerName" or "localhost". So you can rely on this name to define if instance is default. If you rename instance `MSSQLSERVER` then this instance will not be default and to connect to it you will need to use name "ServerName\NewInstanceName".

Comment: @MatRat In my opinion to check if server instance is default by checking its name is better solution than trying to connect to `localhost` and then check if connection is success. But you can implement solution suggested by you (connect to `localhost` and check). I think that this solution does not make many problems because default server instance most of the time exists.

Comment: If you decide to implement your approach you should take into account that if instance does not exist then connection fails by timeout. Default connection timeout - 15 seconds. If you don't change it then your application can hang for 15 seconds (if you try to connect synchronously) whenever default instance does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have noticed that the name localhost varies depending on the version. But I did not know that when changing the name causes it is not default.